# reuse a layer in multiple docker images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have numerous microservices all running on centos. I don't know if it's possible but is there a way to get the `OS Layer` and reuse it when building the image ?

Comment: The thing is, that Sergey gave you only solution. The one You were looking for (and me today) will never be. Further reading https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/735

Answer (score 1):

You can create some base image e.g. `MyBaseImage:latest`, push them to repository. And you can build another images based on first image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM MyBaseImage:latest // <- new image will be build based on this image
...ohter commands
```

Comment: That's not what I'm really trying to do.. actually I'm trying to find a way to do for example: import Layer1 from Image1, import Layer2 from Image3, build image with layer1, layer2